# How to set extra attributes to <option> element when using ng-options construct?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

Given following angularjs it creates a dropdown setting  value and text:

```
colors = { '1': 'red', '2': 'green','3':'blue' };

<select name='colors' ng-options="id as color for (id,color) in colors"></select>
```

Which will create:

```
<select name='colors'>
  <option value="1">red</option>
  <option value="2">green</option>
  <option value="3">blue</option>
</select>
```

what if I want to add extra attribute to each option elment e.g

```
<select name='colors'>
  <option class="red" value="1">red</option>
  <option class="green" value="2">green</option>
  <option class="blue" value="2">blue</option>
</select>
```

Comment: is the class value will be available from json object? or is it fixed for all the options?

Comment: the class value will be available from json object , probably the text attribute is class itself. check the edits

Comment: I think ng-options will not help you, then you may have to use ng-repeat.